# What package is create_StateVals under please?

Tags: r, install.packages

I was just wondering, does anybody here know what package `create_StateVals` is under? I put into RStudio `library(create_StateVals)` and got

```
Error in library(create_StateVals) : 
  there is no package called ‘create_StateVals’
```

meaning that create_StateVals is not yet installed into my RStudio. I asked CHATGPT and it said that I need to install the package it is under, but it didn't know what package this was.
I was just wondering if anybody here knows what package create_StateVals is under, please?

Comment: google suggests `hesim` contains the desired function. You would, `install.packages('hesim', dependencies = TRUE)` to acquire. Welcome to Stackoverflow, or as better suggested, select the one that fits your goals.

Comment: Is looks like there are several packages with functions that use that name: https://rdrr.io/search?q=create_StateVals. I guess it depends on what exactly you expect the function to do as to which one you should use.